# How do I combine two queries and get data into one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, select

I have a situation here to get data(i.e. fname and lname) from two different table comparing their jobid, deliverymanid, pickupmanid and employeeid from job and employee table and combine it in one row.

This is the job table

```
jobid  pickupmanid  deliverymanid
-----  -----------  -------------
  1         1            2
  2         2            2
```

This is the employee table

```
employeeid     fname         lname
----------  -----------  -------------
    1           ABC          XYZ
    2           LMN          OPR
```

Here pickupmanid and deliverymanid act as a foreign keys for job table referring to employeeid in employee table.

Comment: `select fname,lname from tblJob J INNER JOIN tblEmp E on J.deliverymanid = E.employeeid`

Answer (score 4):

You could join the `job` table on the `employee` table twice - once for the picker-upper and once for the deliveryman:

```
SELECT j.jobid, 
       p.fname AS pickup_fname, p.lname AS pickup_lname,
       d.fname AS delivery_fname, d.lname AS delivry_lname
FROM   job j
JOIN   employee p ON p.employeeid = j.pickupmanid
JOIN   employee d ON d.employeeid = j.deliverymanid
```